# Display a separate error page from Python?

Tags: python, html, cgi

I'm trying to write a python script that gets called by a CGI from from an HTML page. In case of an error, I want to be able to generate and open a separate error page with a link back to my original page. If there is no error, I need to display something else.. for that portion, will I have to generate a separate page again, or can I simply append text to my original page and redisplay it? And if so, would I be able to do that simply by writing:

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<center>Output string here</center>"
```

Within my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are serval options:

- Pure Python - Yes, there have to be a new page. Because a link back to the original page means another HTTP request and there will be a new page to show the result of the second request.  Here is some pseudo-code:

  ```
  if there_is_an_error:
      print "error message"
      print '<a href="http_link_to_the_original_page.html"/>'
  else:
      print "something else"
  ```
- With Javascript - No. Javascript is a language that running in the browser(client side) which can change everything on the current web page. When link is clicked, Javascript can make a [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) request and change the content of current page based on the response. With Javascript and Ajax, your website can even build on one page.

Comment: Ok, so I know I can create and write to a new html file from the script, but how do I open it from the script? Or open an existing file from the script and redirect the browser to it?

Comment: What do you mean "open it"? Open the new web page? Just give it a link to the page you want to show and CGI will take care about the rest. Let me update the answer to